# How to take the result of one script and feed it into another?

Tags: javascript

I'm in way over my head here and need some help to understand what I'm looking at please! (Very new to Javascript!) Here is the situation as I understand it...

I have a script that is selecting a single line from a paragraph of text, and currently produces this alert, where '1' is the selected line:

```
alert(getLine("sourcePara", 1));
```

...Instead of triggering an alert I need this selected text to feed into this separate script which is sending data to another browser window. Presently it's taking a text field from a form with the id 'STOCK1', but that can be replaced:

```
function sendLog() {
    var msg = document.getElementById('STOCK1').value;
    t.send('STK1', msg);
}
```

I'm totally confused as to what form this text data is taking on the way out of the first script and have no idea how to call it in as the source for the second... HELP!

All the thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the source code for the Local Connection element;

```
function LocalConnection(options) {

    this.name = 'localconnection';

    this.id = new Date().getTime();

    this.useLocalStorage = false;

    this.debug = false;

    this._actions= [];

    this.init = function(options) {

        try {
            localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.id);
            localStorage.removeItem(this.id);
            this.useLocalStorage = true;
        } catch(e) {
            this.useLocalStorage = false;
        }
        for (var o in options) {
            this[o] = options[o];
        }
        this.clear();
    }

    this.listen = function() {
        if (this.useLocalStorage) {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener('storage', this.bind(this, this._check), false);
            } else {
                window.attachEvent('onstorage', this.bind(this, this._check));
            }
        } else {
            setInterval(this.bind(this, this._check), 100);
        }
    }

    this.send = function(event) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return this._write(event, args);
    }

    this.addCallback = function(event, func, scope) {
        if (scope == undefined) {
            scope = this;
        }
        if (this._actions[event] == undefined) {
            this._actions[event] = [];
        }
        this._actions[event].push({f: func, s: scope});
    }

    this.removeCallback = function(event) {
        for (var e in this._actions) {
            if (e == event) {
                delete this._actions[e];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    this._check = function() {
        var data = this._read();
        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (var e in data) {
                this._receive(data[e].event, data[e].args);
            }
        }
    }

    this._receive = function(event, args) {
        if (this._actions[event] != undefined) {
            for (var func in this._actions[event]) {
                if (this._actions[event].hasOwnProperty(func)) {
                    this.log('Triggering callback "'+event+'"', this._actions[event]);
                    var callback = this._actions[event][func];
                    callback.f.apply(callback.s, args);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    this._write = function(event, args) {
        var events = this._getEvents();
        var evt = {
            id: this.id,
            event: event,
            args: args
        };
        events.push(evt);
        this.log('Sending event', evt);
        if (this.useLocalStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem(this.name, JSON.stringify(events));
        } else {
            document.cookie = this.name + '=' + JSON.stringify(events) + "; path=/";
        }
        return true;
    }

    this._read = function() {
        var events = this._getEvents();
        if (events == '') {
            return false;
        }
        var ret = [];

        for (var e in events) {
            if (events[e].id != this.id) {
                ret.push({
                    event: events[e].event,
                    args: events[e].args
                });
                events.splice(e, 1);
            }
        }
        if (this.useLocalStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem(this.name, JSON.stringify(events));
        } else {
            document.cookie = this.name + '=' + JSON.stringify(events) + "; path=/";
        }
        return ret;
    }

    this._getEvents = function() {
        return this.useLocalStorage ? this._getLocalStorage() : this._getCookie();
    }

    this._getLocalStorage = function() {
        var events = localStorage.getItem(this.name);
        if (events == null) {
            return [];
        }
        return JSON.parse(events);
    }

    this._getCookie = function() {
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        var data;
        for (var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(this.name+'=') == 0) {
                data = c.substring(this.name.length+1, c.length);
                break;
            }
        }
        data = data || '[]';
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }

    this.clear = function() {
        if (this.useLocalStorage) {
            localStorage.removeItem(this.name);
        } else {
            document.cookie = this.name + "=; path=/";
        }
    }

    this.bind = function(scope, fn) {
        return function () {
            fn.apply(scope, arguments);
        };
    }

    this.log = function() {
        if (!this.debug) {
            return;
        }
        if (console) {
            console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        }
    }
    this.init(options);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have no clue what "sending data to another browser window" means. Any way you can clarify that?

Comment: You can use `Window.postMessage` to send data between windows... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @JohanP Added the source code for that element to my post above. Thanks!

Comment: @dana Many thanks, although I am already happy with the data sending element - I'm just looking for a way to 'feed' it text selected by the other script

Comment: I think @dana was talking to me

Comment: @JohanP My bad!

Comment: For the record, I was actually talking to @Ben :) No biggie though, I don't thing postMessage is necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for correctly, then I think its a matter of changing your log function to the following:

```
function sendLog() {
    t.send('STK1', getLine("sourcePara", 1));
}
```

This assumes that `getLine` is globally accessible.

---

**Alternatively** Another approach would be to allow for the `sendLog` function to take the message as a parameter.  In which case, you would change your first script to be:

```
sendLog(getLine("sourcePara", 1));
```

And the modified `sendLog` function would look like this:

```
function sendLog(msg) {
    t.send('STK1', msg);
}
```

---

LocalConnection.js should handle transferring the data between windows/tabs.  Looks like an an iteresting project:

https://github.com/jeremyharris/LocalConnection.js

Comment: Wonderful! Many thanks indeed! 

My final challenge seems to be re-running those scripts on a button click to update the editable source paragraph. I don't seem to be able to trigger them all, as the getLine will have to re-consider it's selection. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think that I completely understand... But if you know what parameters to feed into `getLine()`, then you can always call `sendLog(getLine(x, y))` with appropriate x/y parameters.  Is this something that can be determined at the time of button click?